# Closed source library - endianness - negative -1 is read as 0 when deserializing

Tags: c++, floating-point, deserialization, endianness

I am reading some floats from a binary xml and deserealize them into a struct containing 4 floats (32 bit floats to be exact). All the values get read correctly, except for those that are -1.

*Is this an endian-related issue?*

What should I look for if `-1` is converted to `0` and *every* other value is correctly deserialized? (I mean, is there an obvious, common mistake or source for a mistake I should take into account?). I do not have any access to the library that does this and I can't provide you with any details since it's confidential.

Before this question really gets closed, I'd like to post a small hint (no code due to a harsh NDA condition):

- the library I'm working with converts some binary data from an xml to its specific types
- it does this in a very ugly way:

  value = *(T*)srcBuffer;

  SwapByte(value);
- `-1` is thus directly read and assumed to be in BigEndian format. Unfortunately, `-1` amounts to `somethingE-47` which is indeed a very small number in BigEndian format. The assembly instructions perform some quantization *and* round it to zero. The ulterior `SwapByte` instruction will thus get the wrong data and fail for this odd case. It is an architectural problem related to an IBM/PowerPC processor.

Would a `memcpy` work better and avoid the ugly quantization artifact? I can't do the swapbyte before the conversion as I will surely deteriorate other parts.

Comment: I'd look for -1 being used internally in the closed-source library for some special purpose (e.g., to indicate an error).  Sounds very unlikely to be related to endianness.

Comment: `-1` in floating point is quite different from `0` with the bits reversed, so I'm pretty sure this is not an endian-issue, but something to do with how -1 is used in the library.

Comment: Highly unlikely it is endian-related, especially since all your other values as *correct*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. yes, doesn't sound like a conversion problem - I can't dig any deeper since I'm not that good with assembly to reverse engineer the lib. I'll try and maybe post some assembly code when I get it.

Comment: Can you ask a developper of the lib about what is -1 representing in their code ?

Comment: Can you post some of the binary data? Preferably including a place where you are getting valid data and a place where you expect a 01.